# How do I display images from Google Drive on a website?

Tags: html, url, google-drive-api

A client of mine has uploaded some photos to their [Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B4QTOLODWzqaRFpxcWk3TjgtTEk/edit?pli=1) and would like me to display their photos on their company website. I reviewed the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/publish-site) for displaying Google Drive content on a web page, but it appears that this is simply the instructions for displaying the contents on a web page, which it already does.

My question is, how do I display the contents directly on the client's web page?

Comment: Google Drive Hosting is now deprecated.  It stopped working August 31, 2016. [Hosting Deprecation Schedule](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en)

Comment: TL;DR : Use the "Get Link" option in Google Drive to get the URL and change **/open?** to **/uc?** (eg: `https://drive.google.com/open?id=xyz` to `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=xyz`). [CREDITS: @Richard who gave the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34994471/3931192)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have some image files, just upload them to a **public** folder on your Google Drive, copy its **folder ID** from the address bar (e.g. *0B0Gi4v5omoZUVXhCT2kta1l0ZG8*) and paste it into a form at [GDrives](http://gdriv.es) to choose your own alias (e.g. *myimgs*) - and voila! You can access the images one by one using e.g. http://gdriv.es/myimgs/myimage.jpg.

If you want to embed a whole folder on your website (in a frame), you can use one of the following URLs, replacing [folderID] with your own ID:

- [https://docs.google.com/folder/d/[folderID]/preview?rm=minimal](https://docs.google.com/folder/d/%5BfolderID%5D/preview?rm=minimal)
- [https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=[folderID]](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=%5BfolderID%5D)

If you prefer to get the file list in XML or JSON, you can use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22https%3A//googledrive.com/host/0B_p1jUoXa8fqVG9sd0dXdFl5R2c/%22%20and%20xpath%3D%27//div%5b@class%3D%22folder-cell%22%5d/a%27).

Note: You can use **Google + Photos** to host and embed your images as well.

Comment: Folder ids are more than 28 characters, which is how long GDrives is expecting the id to be.  It works for files, but it seems to be broken with folders now.

Comment: Doesn't work for me for photos either due to the character limit.

Comment: GDrives uses [Google Drive Hosting](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en), which will be discontinued on August 31, 2016.

Comment: griv.es doesn't seem relevant anymore

Comment: Exactly: https://gdriv.es/ is totally irrelevant now. I couldn't access my public images through my embedded code on my homepage on https://sites.google.com/.

Answer (score 193):

### Example of Embedding a Google Drive Image

Original URL:

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/0B6wwyazyzml-OGQ3VUo0Z2thdmc=w1000?authuser=1/view
```

Get the Id from the url(followed by the `/d/`)

```
https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=0B6wwyazyzml-OGQ3VUo0Z2thdmc&sz=w1000
```

The image below is embedded using this method:

[image]

HTML tag as used above:

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=0B6wwyazyzml-OGQ3VUo0Z2thdmc&sz=w1000">
```

Photo by [Paula Borowska](https://unsplash.com/fr/@paulaborowska).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Google Drive</title>
</head>
<body>
     <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=0B6wwyazyzml-OGQ3VUo0Z2thdmc&sz=w1000" alt="Page Image">
    <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Updated on: Jan/2024

Comment: Aathi, It does not work for me. Even in codepen if I use my drive link, It does not display the image. Is there any setting that we need to provide in the drive for the file?

Comment: @Aakriti.G Are you sure you are using the right id?. I manage to copy past the folder id not the image id for a while. You need to open the image in a new tab to get the ID in the URL.

Comment: This works really well. Make sure its a public folder in gDrive and get the shareable link. I am using a spreadsheet where I paste the gDrive generated shareable link into a cell, then use this formula to adapt it to the purposes described herein: 

Replace([Img gDrive URL],1,33,"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=")

Comment: Perfect :+1: worked for me!
Also needed to work out how to add custom HTML to gmail signature, but managed it all in the end and this works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: This works in August 2021. 
Note: 
1. My image was inside a folder. I did not make any changes for that. 
2. I had to make changes in the image. Rt click: **Get Link**>**Anyone with the link** choose **Editors** from dropdown

Comment: I get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error when i try to access that url. Does anyone have an solution for that?

Comment: I like that you give a demo using a real link. If we can see it, it means it's still working :D

Comment: Since January 11th or so, this solution is not working, there's a Google Issue Tracker for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/319531488, maybe they resolve it, maybe not.

Comment: I found what I was looking for, thank you. Even ChatGPT couldn't find it.

Answer (score 121):

Use the 'Get Link' option in Google Drive to get the URL.

Use `<img>` tag in HTML and paste the link in there.

Change `Open?` in the URL to `uc?`.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. This has been killing me all day - where did you learn this little gem for a "trick" (uc) and why the heck isn't more widely known. Now to get back to making awesomeness with Fusion Tables.

Comment: AMAZING! Working in 2017!

Comment: Hmmm, the usual incantation is uc?export=view&id=..., but seems the export=view is the default!  (export=download to trigger the save dialog can come handy too)

Comment: Chrome can't seem to cache it

Comment: Wow Man! What a trick! This issue ruined me 2 days. Working in 2018 as well!

Comment: Not for me; my links are of the type `https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXXX/view?usp=sharing`

Comment: Yeah, seems this answer is outdated. 

Comment: you can use the link provided in @quitiweb's answer: <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=XXX"> and replace the XXX with the ID that's in the URL you get when you go to 'Get Link' :^)

Comment: this on iphones doesnt work

Answer (score 76):

I have found a way to do it without using external sites.

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=XXX">
```

https://gist.github.com/evansims/f23e2f49e3d4be793038

```
<a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=XXX">
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=XXX"
    style="width: 500px; max-width: 100%; height: auto"
    title="Click for the larger version." />
</a>
```

You'll need to grab the ID of the image: Click on “Open in new window” and get the ID from the URL.

[image: Click on “Open in new window”]

Comment: Is there a way to scrape that id automatically?

Comment: I haven't found a way to do it, I'm afraid

Comment: use regex to extract maybe

Comment: Yup (Sept 2019)

Comment: A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute.

Comment: This worked for me.  Getting the ID, and sticking it on the end of the custom Google URL link worked.

Comment: @mando222 You can scrape IDs using the Google Drive API.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to work for `.heic` image files but does work for `.jpg` - anyone know how to make this work for `.heic` image files?

Answer (score 14):

I have the same problem right now but this article helps me. Updates for the year 2020!

I got the solution from this article: 
https://dev.to/imamcu07/embed-or-display-image-to-html-page-from-google-drive-3ign

These are the steps from the article:

1. Upload your image to Google drive.
2. Share your image from the sharing option.
3. Copy your sharing link (Sample: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/14hz3ySPn-zBd4Tu3NtY1F05LSGdFfWvp/view?usp=sharing`)
4. Copy the id from your link, in the above link, the id is: `14hz3ySPn-zBd4Tu3NtY1F05LSGdFfWvp`
5. Have a look at this link and replace the ID: `https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1jNWSPr_BOSbm7iIJQTTbl7lXX06NH9_r`

   After the ID is replaced: `https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=14hz3ySPn-zBd4Tu3NtY1F05LSGdFfWvp`
6. Now insert the link to your `<img>` tag.

Comment: Unfortunately this method only gives you a small 200px wide version of your image (a thumbnail). But if you visit the `/thumbnail...` URL, you'll be redirected to a new URL that has a number at the end which you can modify to get any size image you want. Amazing!

Comment: This works great for email `html` signatures!

Answer (score 11):

**Update 18/02/2017**
Google had depreciated free hosting feature on Google drive and now you cannot host your static website on Google drive for free.

But if you want to host your JavaScript and CSS and Images file on Google drive then you can still do so. You just need to obtain the permalink of the file. following updated tutorial (2017).

http://www.bloggerseolab.com/2017/02/host-images-javascript-and-css-on-google-drive.html

Comment: This is the updated answer and most relevant answer! @fmz

Comment: Link is no longer active.

Comment: @eskimwier you can check this alternative [link](http://archive.is/oyUvL)

Comment: Well, dead-link is one of the reason why Stack Overflow really discourage link-only answer.

Answer (score 10):

From [google drive help pages](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en):

> To host a webpage with Drive:
>
> 1. Open Drive at drive.google.com and select a file.
> 2. Click the Share button at the top of the page.
> 3. Click Advanced in the bottom right corner of the sharing box.
> 4. Click Change....
> 5. Choose On - Public on the web and click Save.
> 6. Before closing the sharing box, copy the document ID from the URL in the field below "Link to share". The document ID is a string of
>      uppercase and lowercase letters and numbers between slashes in the
>      URL.
> 7. Share the URL that looks like "www.googledrive.com/host/[doc id] where [doc id] is replaced by the document ID you copied in step 6.
>
> Anyone can now view your webpage.

If you want to see your image in a website embed the link to pic in your html as usually:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example image from Google Drive</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Example image from Google Drive</h1>

        <img src="https://www.googledrive.com/host/[doc id]" alt="whatever">

    </body>
</html>
```

Note:

> Beginning August 31st, 2015, web hosting in Google Drive for users and developers will be deprecated. You can continue to use this feature for a period of one year until August 31st, 2016, when we will discontinue serving content via googledrive.com/host/[doc id]. [More info](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20GoogleAppsDeveloperBlog%20(Google%20Apps%20Developer%20Blog))

Comment: Hosting on Google Drive to be deprecated soon.  [hosting on Google Drive - deprecation](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en)

Comment: No longer works due to hosting being disabled last year

Answer (score 10):

Extension of the above-mentioned answer. I wrote a UNIX command so I can easily do it in my workflow.

1. Copy the Google Drive photos URL which needs to be converted. E.g.

   Copy Google Drive Image URL

   ```
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXXX/view?usp=sharing
   ```
2. Open the terminal and execute this command.

   Command:

   ```
   echo https://drive.google.com/uc\?export\=view\&id\=`echo $(pbpaste) | cut -d '/' -f 6`
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=XXXX
   ```

If you copy the command from here. Make sure to copy the Google Drive image URL again.

No need to change anything in the Step 2 command as it takes from clipboard. Make sure it is copied in right format. For example:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXXX/view?usp=sharing
```

Comment: i am using in php so i used explode('d/',url); it works grate thank you

Answer (score 8):

if you want to embedded Google drive images in your blogger or any sites then just follow the instructions : -

**Blogger**

1. upload the image on google drive
2. click on image and share with public
3. `<img src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&amp;id=1OCx6mUEMbWcwCQbDePA5PeeOh'/>`

Answer (score 8):

This method allows you to embed the image at whatever size or resolution you need:

1. Create a folder in your Google Drive
2. Make the folder (or image itself) public via the "Share" button
3. Copy the URL and extract the ID. It should look like
   `https://drive.google.com/file/d/ID-HERE/view?usp=sharing`
4. Use something like this as your image src:
   `https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=${imageId}&sz=w${width || 200}-h${height || 200}`

   Example:
   `https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=ID-HERE&sz=w200-h200`

You can modify the numbers after `w` and `h` to get whatever size you need. The image will be shrunk to fit inside those dimensions.

Comment: Great tip! I love how this option allows you to scale the image to whatever size you need.

Comment: Also make sure you've made the image public with "`Anyone with link`"

Comment: &sz=w${width || 200}-h${height || 200} and &sz=w200-h200 are not working for me

Answer (score 5):

Google Drive Hosting is now deprecated.  It stopped working from August 31, 2016.

[hosting on Google Drive - deprecation schedule](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en)

I have removed the explanation of how to previously host an image on Google Drive.

Comment: Hosting on Google Drive to be deprecated.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

List View

`<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=YOURID#list"     width="700" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Grid View

`<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=YOURID#grid"     width="700" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Read More at:
https://thomas.vanhoutte.be/miniblog/embed-add-google-drive-folder-file-website/

Comment: How to increase the size of the images inside the iframe

Answer (score 4):

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=Your_Image_ID" alt="">
```

I use on my wordpress site as storing image files on local host takes up to much space and slows down my site

I use textmate as it is easy to edit multiple URLs at same time using the 'alt/option' button

Answer (score 4):

Based in different answers I created a tool to help creating the HTML Embed Code or the direct link.

1. Copy the Google drive URL.

   ```
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/18RX_EwpYdZsKU0QobLvNidmhvqJPEhrH/view?usp=sharing
   ```
2. Pass the URL to [this tool](https://embed.yayocode.com/) (check screenshot) and click generate link, the result will be like this:

   ```html
   <a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=18RX_EwpYdZsKU0QobLvNidmhvqJPEhrH"> <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=18RX_EwpYdZsKU0QobLvNidmhvqJPEhrH" width="100%"/></a>
   ```

- How to use the tool: https://yayocode.com/post/DUt9Wf5e48AUEqzWSiyX
- Link to the tool here: https://embed.yayocode.com/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Upload the image at a specic folder at dgrive.
2. Make this image as view for who is having the link.
3. copy the link, something like:

   ```
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/IMAGE_ID/edit
   ```
4. Take the image ID from the link.
5. Use the image ID with th below link:

   ```
   drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=IMAGE_ID
   ```

This reference is very helpful for fixing HTML5 images at outlook:

- https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how-to-code-emails-for-outlook-2016/#images

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a better way but you can datamine the page with php.  For instance if you go to google and share a folder then go to that folder it will look something like

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8TT0olkjsdkfji9jekbFF4LWc&usp=sharing

^^^ not a real link

What you are looking for is the individual images inside the source code of this page

then using php get the source code with

```
<? $f = fopen ("http://www.example.com/f", r);
echo $f;
?>
```

now $f has the source and you can use other php commands to seperate only the URLS with the images you want.  It will take a bit of work but highly doable.

once you have these image links showing the way you want just build them into a div or table structure to display on a gallery maybe even add a greybox element for effect

Answer (score 0):

A couple interesting alternatives to publicly hosting an image on Drive (deprecated):

**1. Google Photos**

If you upload an image to Google Photos instead of Drive it gets a public web link.

This behavior is a little surprising to me, but the link is very long and random, so they are apparently practicing "privacy by obscurity."

**2. Google Drawing**

If you *create* an image using the ["Google Drawing" program](https://docs.google.com/drawing) (built into Drive) you can press `File > Publish to Web` to get a public link.

[image]

Note: This *could* be a solution if you're trying to share an existing image-- paste the image into the editor and crop the canvas to your image (`file > Page Setup`)-- but it's a little cumbersome. If you need to do some basic image editing, though, or if you're trying create a simple icon/graphic, I think this is nifty.

Answer (score 0):

As [this Spanish blog](https://clasicwebtools.com/articulos/programacion/host-fotos-GDrive.html) explains and provides a link convertor.

1. Upload your image to your Google drive.
2. Share it with anyone on the web.
3. Copy the sharing link.

Then you can use the converter that [ClasicWebTools](https://clasicwebtools.com/articulos/programacion/host-fotos-GDrive.html) provides to use it on your web.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><iframe frameborder="0" height="1000px" src="https://drive.google.com/[folder address]/embeddedfolderview?id=[folder id]#grid" width="100%"></iframe></p>
```

you could easily get the folder id, just right mouse click on the folder, copy the share link and paste some text/Html file  there you get the folder id

Example of Embed a Google Drive

```
<p><iframe frameborder="0" height="1000px" src="https://drive.google.com/a/esn.ac.lk/embeddedfolderview?id=19FWi2HI98Gim6VjZfHT391EBClO8Jxco#grid" width="100%"></iframe></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
import urllib.parse 

def transform_google_drive_link(original_link):
    parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(original_link)
    query_params = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
    
    # The file ID should be in the 'd' path component
    file_id = parsed_url.path.split('/')[-2]
    
    # Construct the new URL for embedding the image
    embeddable_url = f"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={file_id}"
    
    return embeddable_url
```

Answer (score -2):

If the file is in a public folder, you can use [Google Drive website hosting](https://developers.google.com/drive/publish-site).

Comment: Hi Ali, this doesn't address the issue of displaying the images on the client's website. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, it does if you get the URL, and put it in an <img src="... tag. The URL won't change.

Comment: That is individually though. Correct? There isn't a feed or something that I could do to accomplish this?

Comment: The link is dead now.