# jupyter notebook image doesnt show when uploaded to cloud notebooks such as colaboratory or azure notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Newbie data analyst here.

I am taking data science course on udacity and my work setup is ubuntu vm and have jupyter notebook installed using anaconda, then git cloned the course study files. everything is fine there, images, formulas and all show up fine (local).

**problem:**then at work I often have a lot of free time, so I downloaded the course file, and uploaded to Google Colaboratory and Azure notebook but both notebook somehow **doesn't show the image** even though they are uploaded. If ipynb notebook file is on root, then images are in images folder, then I assumed  I can do
 but image doesn't show up although it shows up fine on local. The same for Google Colab and while I'm aware that I need to do some different stuff like . Any advice appreciated.

[image file not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GAqK.png)

Answer (score 1):

Markdown in colab can't refer to images stored in the VM. Instead you either need to render the image as the output of a code-cell, or use markdown to point at a publicly-viewable copy of the image, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50672083/8755609
(assuming the image is static, the latter is probably your best bet).