# Is there a change for reading the published CSV from Google Sheets in Google Colab?

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-colaboratory

I have been using a file from Google sheets, published as CSV, and reading it with Pandas, to make the dataframe, but today stopped working here it is the error output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
```

2155     def read(self, nrows=None):
2156         try:
-> 2157             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
2158         except StopIteration:
2159             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2

If I use the same sheet, but reading it directly from a CSV file from Google Drive, there's no problem, and it's working perfectly.

If I use:

df= pd.read_csv(url,sep='\t', lineterminator='\r')

There's no errror in reading the data, but I got this, when trying to read the df:

[image: Error reading the DF]

Hopefully is something similar, to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670920/how-to-insert-an-inline-image-in-google-colaboratory-from-google-drive)?
Thanks in advance for your attention!

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use `pd.read_csv` on a HTML file.

Comment: Previously it worked, pretty good since Google Sheets have the option to publish as CSV until now, that I got the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is a bug

See this link:
https://issuetracker.google.com/173534863

Go give it a ☆ to let Google know that this affects you.

The workaround as you have said, is to change the permissions of the file to be viewable by "Anyone with link". Previously this was not necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much ^_^ glad to know that is a bug and it's already reported!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, Google changes the option for the files, if you select publish as csv, just make sure also have activated, the option: Anyone with the link can see :)