# Import Image from Google Drive to Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have mounted my Google drive to my colab notebook:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/gdrive")
```

I can import csv files through it, in my case:

```
df = pd.read_csv("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/colab/heart-disease.csv")
```

But when I try to import images in markdown/text in colab
nothing happens:

```
![](/content/gdrive/MyDrive/colab/6-step-ml-framework.png)
```

Here's my directory on Google drive:

[image: Directory]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can using **OpenCV** in colab by `import cv2 as cv`, read image by `img = cv.imread('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/colab/6-step-ml-framework.png')`, convert image to numpy array using `img = np.float32(img)`

Comment: how do i print the photo out?

Comment: There many ways, you can using `matplotlib` as usual, or `from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow` then `cv2_imshow(img)`, check out this [image processing tutorial on colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/xn2333/OpenCV/blob/master/Image_Processing_in_Python_Final.ipynb#scrollTo=Tz7UAjxjfMuz)

Comment: in markdown text 
i want to use this Image

Comment: @gamemovie it seems you cannot directly using it, but you could do so by follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670920/how-to-insert-an-inline-image-in-google-colaboratory-from-google-drive), or just upload it from your PC

Answer (score 1):

@Mr. For Example
you should not use `np.float(img)`, because OpenCV's method `imread` has converted it to *np.array* already

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30812887)