# how to read images form a cloud shared services like google drive or other

Tags: google-drive-api, sharing, data-sharing

hi i am working on project in which requirement is i have to upload images on some cloud services like google drive or other, and it generates a URL of images like `http://example.com/images/1.jpg` etc and share this URL with any one.

I already tried this method (but it not fulfill my requirement) :

[How do I display images from Google Drive on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557392/how-do-i-display-images-from-google-drive-on-a-website)

> If you have some image files, just upload them to a public folder on
>   your Google Drive, copy its folder ID from the address bar (e.g.
>   0B0Gi4v5omoZUVXhCT2kta1l0ZG8) and paste it into a form at GDrives,
>   then choose your own alias (e.g. myimgs) and voila! You can access the
>   images one by one using e.g.
>
> ```
> http://gdriv.es/myimgs/myimage.jpg
> ```
>
> If you want to embed a whole folder on your website (in a frame), you can use one of the following URLs, replacing [folderID] with your
>   own ID:
>
> ```
> http://gdriv.es/myimgs/
> https://docs.google.com/folder/d/[folderID]/preview?rm=minimal
> https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=[folderID]
> ```
>
> If you prefer to get the file list in XML or JSON, you can use YQL.
>   Note: You can use Google+ Photos to host ans embed your images as well.

Comment: _"...it generates a URL of images like http://example.com/images/1.jpg"_ so what is the problem here? What is the mysterious requirement that must be fulfilled?