# image not displaying on google sidebar

Tags: html, google-sheets, google-drive-api, png, sidebar

I have an image stored on google drive that has been shared so that anyone can view.

I am using the following HTML code to apply it to the sidebar in google sheets:

```html
<img alt="Add-on logo" class="logo" width="40"
      src="https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gQLj2pwsPTkBANEJa19FSWN5X7uPvSKC/globe_noglow.png">
```

All I get is "Add-on logo" where I am expecting the logo to be.

Please, can you advise why it will not show?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557392/how-do-i-display-images-from-google-drive-on-a-website)

Comment: Thanks @khaliyeva. Found the answer I needed in this post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I display images from Google Drive on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557392/how-do-i-display-images-from-google-drive-on-a-website)