# Where can I host an image for use in my web page?

Tags: html, html-email, email-attachments

I am making a HTML email. I want my png image to be formatted in a hyper link like:

```
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg">
```

Where can I upload my png image to get a link like above that ends in .png?

I know I can upload my png to files and grab it in files using HTML but I want everything to just be in one file.

Comment: I have a png image, I want upload my image to get a hyperlink like above, so I can link it to my HTML file

Comment: how do I upload image to URI? yes I am looking for a reliable image hosting server. and file type does not matter

Comment: I found my solution in this video: https://youtu.be/s336AarjfLk

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

[Imgur](https://imgur.com/) is free and reliable. Alternatively, just put the image next to your html file and then set the url to just the name of the image

```
<img src="w3schools_green.jpg">
```

Comment: this might work. I just need to know to to remove header share button and footer Imgur

Comment: right click the images you should be able to copy the url of just the image

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using google drive? You can upload your images there and then use its link in the HTML. Here is an explanation of how to do it [How do I display images from Google Drive on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557392/how-do-i-display-images-from-google-drive-on-a-website)

Comment: Yes I have tried google drive and google photos

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]

Answer (score 0):

There are so many image hosting services available, just google "free image hosting" and you will get tons of websites. For PNG specific image hosting you can try: https://www.pngtank.com/en/user-request-png

However, choose your image hosting service wisely because if any of the website deletes your image, it will stop appearing on your website. You can also try storing images locally if this is an option for you.