# How to convert Google drive image into correct format to post it on Instagram using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to post images on Instagram, and for that, I followed a well-detailed StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token/28418469#28418469). The images which I am trying to post on Instagram are coming from my Google drive folder (publicly shared). The code looks like this:

```
function instapost() {
  const access_token = '########....######';
  const instagram_business_account = '########';

  const image = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1SNy876_kwrFBUCZdGfPLaKx6ZdKtYwn0';
  const text = 'subtitle';
  var formData = {
    'image_url': image,
    'caption': text,
    'access_token': access_token
  };
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formData
  };
  const container = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/' + instagram_business_account + '/media';
  // return;
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(container, options);

  const creation = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(creation);
  var creationId = data.id
  var formDataPublish = {
      'creation_id': creationId,
      'access_token': access_token
  };
  var optionsPublish = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formDataPublish
  };
  const sendinstagram = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/' + instagram_business_account + '/media_publish';
  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(sendinstagram, optionsPublish);
}
```

When I run the script, I receive the following error:

> Exception: Request failed for https://graph.facebook.com returned code
> 400. Truncated server response: {"error":{"message":"Only photo or video can be accepted as media
> type.","type":"OAuthException","code":9004,"error_subcode":2207052,"is_transient"...
> (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

I followed different sources ([s1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311092/displaying-files-e-g-images-stored-in-google-drive-on-a-website) - [s2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557392/how-do-i-display-images-from-google-drive-on-a-website)) to publicly access the G-Drive image but it is getting the same error every time, kindly can you guide me on how to convert this image so that it can be posted from Google Drive folder directly.

Comment: In your script, there are 2 `UrlFetchApp.fetch`. About your current error message, where the error does occur in your script? And, can you provide the official document of the API you want to use?

Comment: this is the line with an error `const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(container, options);`, this is the official document of the API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, your issue is your 1st `UrlFetchApp.fetch`. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, you have already confirmed that your 2nd `UrlFetchApp.fetch` works fine. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Actually, the script does not reach 2nd `UrlFetch`, it stops at first `UrlFetchApp.fetch` due to an error, so we can not be sure about the second one.

Comment: if we use this image url, (http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/gutenberg.jpg) which is available online, then script runs successfully.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? In this modification, from your provided official document, I modified your 2 requests. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I saw your provided official document, the values are required to be the query parameter. [Ref](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing) But, in your script, the values are sent as form instead of the query parameter. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function instapost() {
  // Ref: https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/70503e0ea6998083fcb05c6d2a857107
  String.prototype.addQuery = function (obj) {
    return this + Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (p, e, i) {
      return p + (i == 0 ? "?" : "&") +
        (Array.isArray(obj[e]) ? obj[e].reduce(function (str, f, j) {
          return str + e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(f) + (j != obj[e].length - 1 ? "&" : "")
        }, "") : e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[e]));
    }, "");
  }

  const access_token = '########....######';
  const instagram_business_account = '########';
  const image = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1SNy876_kwrFBUCZdGfPLaKx6ZdKtYwn0'; // or "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1SNy876_kwrFBUCZdGfPLaKx6ZdKtYwn0&export=download"
  const text = 'subtitle';
  var query1 = {
    'image_url': image,
    'caption': text,
    'access_token': access_token
  };
  const container = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/' + instagram_business_account + '/media';
  const endpoint1 = container.addQuery(query1);
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint1, { method: 'post' });

  const creation = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(creation);
  var creationId = data.id
  var query2 = {
    'creation_id': creationId,
    'access_token': access_token
  };
  const sendinstagram = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/' + instagram_business_account + '/media_publish';
  const endpoint2 = sendinstagram.addQuery(query2);
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint2, { method: 'post' });
}
```

#### Note:

- I think that the request for this modified script is the same as the sample HTTP requests of the official document you provided. But, unfortunately, I cannot test this script. So, when an error occurs, please confirm the values of query parameters and your access token again.
- If your image URL cannot be used, please test the following URL. In this case, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.

  ```
    const image = Drive.Files.get("1SNy876_kwrFBUCZdGfPLaKx6ZdKtYwn0").thumbnailLink.replace(/\=s.+/, "=s1000");
  ```

#### References:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [Content Publishing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing)

Comment: Thank you so much, this suggested line `const image = Drive.Files.get("1SNy876_kwrFBUCZdGfPLaKx6ZdKtYwn0").thumbnailLink.replace(/\=s.+/, "=s1000");` works like a magic for both scripts (my existing script and your suggested script)

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: one more request, when I run this script it posts image with a caption, I want to show the URL of image (`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1SNy876_kwrFBUCZdGfPLaKx6ZdKtYwn0`) as a clickable hyperlink at the top of the image in place of the caption, is that possible? thank you

Comment: @Roomi About your new question of `one more request, when I run this script it posts image with a caption, I want to show the URL of image (https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1SNy876_kwrFBUCZdGfPLaKx6ZdKtYwn0) as a clickable hyperlink at the top of the image in place of the caption, is that possible?`, I would like to support you. But, I cannot understand your new question. So, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand your new question, I would like to think of a solution. I apologize that I cannot resolve your various questions soon.