# How to Embedding a Google Drive image in HTML?

Tags: html

Copying links directly from Google Drive and using on HTML pages but image does not show on web page.

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PBXfGMt4AuAZGyMGvFpvdmHY5-K4azXi/view?usp=drive_link" alt="National Flag of Bangladesh" width="300" height="200">
```

How to Embed a Google Drive image in HTML?

Comment: Your URL you have added is not an image, it's a HTML file. You have to use an URL which points to an image.

Comment: You might want to look at https://www.labnol.org/google-drive-image-hosting-220515 on how to get/generate the correct image URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying files (e.g. images) stored in Google Drive on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311092/displaying-files-e-g-images-stored-in-google-drive-on-a-website)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I display images from Google Drive on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557392/how-do-i-display-images-from-google-drive-on-a-website)

Answer (score 1):

You have to write it in this way.

[https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id={yourfileid}](https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=%7Byourfileid%7D)

so in your case,

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1PBXfGMt4AuAZGyMGvFpvdmHY5-K4azXi" alt="National Flag of Bangladesh" width="300" height="200">
```

Keep it in your mind that you should make your image file in google drive to be sharable for anyone (in view). Otherwise, other people cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it. Google Drive Is a place where you upload your files but it is not work like that. You have to upload your images on [Imagekit.io](https://imagekit.io/) or any other platforms

Answer (score 0):

The encoded part "1PBXfGMt4AuAZGyMGvFpvdmHY5-K4azXi" in the Google Drive link URL is the Google Drive File ID, so you can take that File ID and replace GOOGLE_DRIVE_FILE_ID in the URL below:

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=GOOGLE_DRIVE_FILE_ID" alt="My Google Drive File ID" />
```