# Using google drive link as img src on React app not working

Tags: html, reactjs, image, frontend

I'm working on a React app using a Google Drive link as the src for an image. The link has this format:

[https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={{imageId}}](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=%7B%7BimageId%7D%7D)

It was working fine, but it suddenly stopped working. The link is still public, and I've tested viewing the image in different browsers and using incognito mode.

When I make a GET request to the link from the React app, I receive a 403 error. Also, on chrome I see this warning:

Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'ch-ua-form-factor'.

Any hints on how to resolve this and why it suddenly stopped working?

I tried with other images, setting policy headers using meta tags in index.html, and also setting referrerPolicy="no-referrer" on the image, but still not working.

Comment: Don’t use drive as web hosting

Comment: While I understand that using drive for hosting images might not be a conventional choice, it's a current requirement for this project. Could you provide more details on why using drive for hosting is discouraged? This information would help me better understand the potential challenges or limitations involved. Thank you

Comment: It could change at anytime. What if the account hosting the image gets deleted… etc

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I have an application developed in React and it suddenly stopped working (I don't know why).

**SOLUTION**:

If you are importing the image from Google Drive in this way:
<img src={`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=${IMAGE_ID}`} alt={NAME}/>

Import it in this other way:
<img src={`https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=${IMAGE_ID}`} alt={NAME}/>

I leave you the function that I use to normalize the Google Drive link and leave it correctly ready to use in the application:

```
export const **getImage** = (rawURL: string) => {
   const RAW_URL1 = rawURL.split("/d/");
   const RAW_URL2 = RAW_URL1[1].split("/view");
   const IMAGE_ID = RAW_URL2[0];
   return `https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=${IMAGE_ID}`;
};
```

I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Related to [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557392/how-do-i-display-images-from-google-drive-on-a-website), just enter your image ID into this link instead:

```
https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id={{imageId}}&sz=w1000
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked perfectly! I understand it might be a temporary fix, and there could be changes in the future, but for now, it's exactly what I needed. Thanks!