# Power BI the image could not be loaded

Tags: image, powerbi, google-drive-api

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains several image links. All images are in a Google Drive folder.

I carried out the process of making the image link available to anyone. Additionally, I changed their link to have "uc?id=" along with "https://drive.google.com" and the sequence of numbers and letters in the image. It's worth mentioning that I did this following several YouTube tutorials.

I've been using this dashboard for years and the idea is that the image has a filter that shows the person with the highest revenue on the company's day. I had never had a problem, but after a while the message the image "https..." could not be loaded began to appear. At first, I updated the dashboard and the photo appeared, but now only the problem remains.

I already put the images in another Google Drive account and it didn't work. I've already recreated the links as explained before and in different ways and it didn't work either.

Comment: Update your question with what the issue is and where.

Comment: Refer to [Display images in a table, matrix, or slicer in a report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-images-tables) - and - [How do I display images from Google Drive on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557392/how-do-i-display-images-from-google-drive-on-a-website)